# Matching Nodes by relationship based on Ancestor properties of each Node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, tree-traversal

In a scenario where assemblies of Objects have subassemblies of subassemblies of Objects:

**Assembly 1**

```
A:Object{name:ABC} is PART_OF B:Object{name:DEF} is PART_OF C:Object{name:GHI}
```

**Assembly 2**

```
D:Object{name:JKL} is PART_OF E:Object{name:MNO} is PART_OF F:Object{name:PQR} is PART_OF G:Object{name:STU}
```

and some component object of Assembly 1 is connected to Assembly 2

```
C is JOINED_TO G
```

How to `MATCH` all Objects where *any part* of the assembly chain in Assembly 1 has a given name property that are `JOINED_TO` Objects where *any part* has a given name property

my guess would be:

```
MATCH ob1:Object{name:DEF} - [:PART_OF*] -> ob2:Object - [:JOINED_TO] - ob3:Object <- [:PART_OF*] - ob4:Object{name:PQR}
RETURN ob2, ob3
```

but no amount of 'asciiart' graph play gets me what I expect

```
 ob2    ob3
------------
  C      G
```

Comment: What you show should get you (many, possibly duplicate) result rows. (However, your query is not specifying any name properties). Can you provide some Cypher code to create sample data that shows your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to create your sample graph:

```
CREATE (A:Object{name:'ABC'})-[:PART_OF]->(B:Object{name:'DEF'})-[:PART_OF]->(C:Object{name:'GHI'}),
(D:Object{name:'JKL'})-[:PART_OF]->(E:Object{name:'MNO'})-[:PART_OF]->(F:Object{name:'PQR'})-[:PART_OF]->(G:Object{name:'STU'})
CREATE (C)-[:JOINED_TO]->(G)
```

And I used this to query the graph:

```
MATCH (ob1:Object{name:'DEF'}) - [:PART_OF*] -> (ob2:Object) - [:JOINED_TO] - (ob3:Object) <- [:PART_OF*] - (ob4:Object{name:'PQR'})
RETURN ob2, ob3
```

This correctly returns the two nodes with names 'GHI' and 'STU'.

This query will not return "C" or "G", because you never saved that to your graph. In your creation query "C" and "G" (and all the other single letters used) are variables for the nodes in question. Variables are not saved to the database, and they do not persist after a query has finished. They are for addressing things (nodes, relationships, values, etc) throughout the duration of a query, but not past it.

If you want a query to return "C" and "G" then you should save these as additional properties on the nodes, and return those properties in your RETURN.

Here's the [documentation on variables](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/variables/) from the Cypher developer guide.

Comment: I'll check it out and accept. C&G in the results were shorthand for the full object. What I'm gratified by is how similar your real Cypher is to my crude pseudocypher.